# First and only user gets assigned id 2 at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

After deploying my application I created a new user and noticed that the address bar was reporting number 2 at the end of the url: htt://...herokuapp.com/users/2.

So I checked with rails console in production environment first and then at Heroku. There seemed to be nothing irregular in my production environment (running sqlite3), so I ran `heroku run console --sandbox` and got the following results:

```
irb(main):001:0> User.count
   (4.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
   (4.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
=> 1


irb(main):002:0> User.first
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 2, name: "Mark Homburg", email: "mark.homburg@yahoo.com", created_at: "2015-12-20 13:56:04", updated_at: "2015-12-20 13:56:04", password_digest: "...">


irb(main):001:0> User.find(1)
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=1
```

What is irregular at Heroku is the duplicate SELECT FROM "users" action after running `User.count`, `User.first` and `User.find(1)`. As I said there was nothing irregular in the corresponding commands in my production environment:

```
>> User.find(1)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Rails Tutorial", email: "example@railstutorial.org", created_at: "2015-12-20 10:08:22", updated_at: "2015-12-20 10:08:22", password_digest: "...">
```

In my opinion this could be explained by the presence of a duplicate users table in the database, as I tried to explain in [Duplicate migrations in topic branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295303/duplicate-migrations-in-topic-branch).
What is your opinion and what do you suggest I can do?

Comment: `User.find(1)` give?

Comment: `truncate users` and give a try..